# SSD displaying incorrect size, despite having no unallocated space

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, ssd, clone, gpt

I have a 120GB SSD that I recently copied to a 250GB SSD via a device-device clone on Clonezilla, the clone worked without issue and all of my previous partitions were successfully cloned to the new SSD.

However, after this clone there doesn't seem to be unallocated space on the drive, just 120GB of partitions.

Windows Disk Management is reporting the disk as 111.79GB - with no unallocated space, as does the "Volumes" tab on the drive.

The drive is being correctly identified as a 250GB Samsung SSD, however the full capacity isn't being recognized.

I have attempted to use tools such as MiniTool Partition Wizard to "recognize" the missing space however have failed to do so.

Comment: *The drive is being correctly identified as a 250GB Samsung SSD* Where, exactly?

Comment: @MichaelBay Volume properties, Hardware, All Disk Drives - the 250GB is listed as a disk drive

Comment: Please check device manager and disk manager. Then [edit] the question to include the exact drive model (as shown in device manager) and a screenshot of drive manager showing the partition and, according to your report, not showing the full capacity.

Comment: I think it can help https://superuser.com/a/1065660/249729

Answer (score 5):

I had **exactly** same problem after cloning 256 GB SSD to 512 GB one.

I've solved it *purely by accident* using diskpart.exe while desperately trying out anything related to disk and volume management in Windows:

1. Fire up `diskpart.exe`
2. `SELECT DISK n` (n — whatever your new disk number is. Find number using `LIST DISK` command)
3. `SELECT VOLUME n` (where n is number of **any**
   volume that is located on a problematic disk. Find it using `LIST VOLUME` command)
4. `EXTEND` (without any parameters)

and voilà, you can now see all the unallocated space in Windows Disk Management and can extend an existing volume or add a new one.

I still do not understand what the problem was, but hey, who cares, it is gone now.

Comment: The problem is that partition size doesn’t equal filesystem size. The latter needs to be resized, too, which is what your guide does.

Comment: @DanielB Thanks for clarification. Confusing was the fact, that Windows Disk Management did not made it clear or accessible. Free space was just gone.

Comment: `EXTEND` without any parameters returns error `The size of the extent is less than the minimum` in my case. Microsoft Windows Version 10.0.18363.535.

Comment: EXTEND didn't work, trying to shrink got the "incorrect parameters" error. I disabled bitlocker and booted into Gparted live USB to "check" disk and fix errors, also didn't work. I finally tried to reset the PC, it ran into blue screen of death and started automatically checking disk for errors --> PC restarted and had error "unable to reset PC due to errors". But the problem went away, windows could now see the full drive size. I suspect running windows disk check from advanced startup would have worked

Answer (score 4):

Just got the same problem (in my case it is cloning 1TB to 2TB HDD - I suppose there is no difference between HDD and SSD).

I got the solution (at least it worked with me):

1. **DECREASE**/shrink the volume of your partition (just 1GB)
2. You should see now the total unallocated volume.

I used 3rd party free software for the HDD management, but the built-in windows disk manager should work.

Comment: This worked for me after using Clonezilla, many other solutions were not working.

Comment: @Nimble I suppose this method is almost the same as suggested George Chakhidze, just much more simplier

Answer (score -1):

I had a similar issue with a 256GB Samsung SSD not showing full capacity (it was only showing 111GB capacity).

Went to Disk Management>Delete Volume

Then re-create volume.

The full capacity of 256GB was then available.

Hope this helps anyone with a similar issue

Comment: That's kind of a destructive, last resort solution when simple things don't work.  Are you suggesting that all users with a similar problem start with that ?

Comment: No, thanks. I have lots of data on it. And have no luxury of an external HDD to back it up to.